# php mvc doctrine design

Tags: php, model-view-controller, dojo, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I have a question regarding a custom mvc framework. I am a little confused with how I should implement the models portion. I am thinking since doctrine entities will be my models, then I could create another folder named models in my file structure and within this model folder I will have individual files that will perform the crud functionality. The reason I am trying to do my own framework is that I plan to use dojo mvc on the front-end.

for instance my models folder would look like:

models --> users 
           logger
           blog

and inside say users class some code my look like:

```
class Users{

    public function getUsers(){ 

          $users = $this->em->getRepository('entities\Users')->findAll();
          echo // the data from 
    } 

    // also there will be setUsers, etc...      
}
```

Thanks everyone

Comment: Your approach is fine, go for it. Also you should remember to state explicitly the question next time, otherwise angry SO veterans will bash you with "what's the question?" comments :) I'm assuming your question is something along the lines of "is this design sane?".

Comment: say, if you have an entry point @ '/' and a sample model/view 'Users'. If you separate as you intend to do (use strtolower or lowerCamelCase perhaps), then you will gain an advantage; when entry point detects it should go '/Users' (sent GET/PUT etc from a dojo mvc store) then Only call require_once("users/model.php"); and a minimum of classes are loaded

Comment: Yeah .. this topic is missing the "question" part. It's more like: "here is what i have - discuss".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With in the MVC's Model (at least to [*my*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5864000/727208) comprehension), the Doctrine should be dealing only with information storage and retrieval for *Domain Objects*.

And, depending on how you actually implement the front-end part, you might have a very thin interface (that's what views and controller provide) over the model layer, which basically just provides REST API.

Materials you might be interested in:

- [GUI Architectures](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html)
- [SOLID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design))
- [Law of Demeter](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LawOfDemeter)

.. added the last two, because your code bit feels a bit off.

Comment: Thanks teresko for your comprehension of a model. After reading through the post, it brought me back to my original design of a model. My original design was to create a class named models, and within the models class would consist of functions that perform the business CRUD functionality.